# Adding a list of values to the value itself excluding its own value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a list of textboxes inside a parent div, say 'parentDom'. I need to attach a data attribute 'list' to each of these textboxes which has the list of values of all the textboxes under parentDom, except for itself.

So far, I have this

```
$('input').each(function(index, item) {
     var list = _.pluck(
                     _.reject(
                        $('input'), 
                            function(obj) {
                               return $(obj).data('id') == $(item).attr('id')
                            }
                        ),
                    'name');

    $(item).data('list', list);
});
```

Am using underscore.js. Is this the right way?

Comment: can u explain a bit more or share your html code ?

Comment: And what is the `_` variable?

Comment: @DavidThomas  '_' is underscore variable of underscore.js

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this (assuming I'm interpreting the question correctly) is:

```js
// getting a reference to the relevant <input /> elements:
var inputs = $('#parentDom input');

// iterating over each of those <input /> elements, with attr():
inputs.attr('data-value', function() {
  // creating a reference to the current <input /> over which we're iterating:
  var cur = this;

  return inputs.filter(function() {
    // filtering the jQuery collection to remove the current <input />
    return this !== cur;
  }).map(function() {
    // converting the (string) value to a number, using the
    // unary plus operator:
    return +this.value;
    // creating an array of the values
  }).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    // reducing the array of values to a single value,
    // by summing the previous and current values together:
    return a + b;
  });
});

// inserting a <span> after the <input /> elements,
// just to show the result:
inputs.after(function() {
  return '<span>' + this.dataset.value + '</span>';
});
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0 0 0.4em 0;
}
span {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
span::before {
  content: '(data-value: ';
}
span::after {
  content: ').';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parentDom">
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="2" />
  <input type="text" value="3" />
  <input type="text" value="4" />
  <input type="text" value="5" />
  <input type="text" value="6" />
  <input type="text" value="7" />
</div>
```

A somewhat simpler approach, however, would be:

```js
// getting a reference to the relevant <input /> elements:
var inputs = $('#parentDom input'),
  // finding the total of *all* the <input /> elements:
  totalValue = inputs.map(function() {
    return +this.value;
  }).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });

// iterating over the <input /> elements with attr():
inputs.attr('data-value', function() {
  // setting the data-value attribute to the total value
  // of all the <input /> elements minus the value of the
  // current <input />:
  return totalValue - (+this.value);
});

// inserting a <span> after the <input /> elements,
// just to show the result:
inputs.after(function() {
  return '<span>' + this.dataset.value + '</span>';
});
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0 0 0.4em 0;
}
span {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
span::before {
  content: '(data-value: ';
}
span::after {
  content: ').';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parentDom">
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="2" />
  <input type="text" value="3" />
  <input type="text" value="4" />
  <input type="text" value="5" />
  <input type="text" value="6" />
  <input type="text" value="7" />
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).